# django querying multiple tables - passing parameters to the query

Tags: python, django, django-1.7

I am using Django 1.7.

I am trying to implement a search functionality. When a search term is entered, I need to search all the tables and all the columns for that term in the DB(I have only 7 tables and probably 40 columns in total and the DB is not very huge). I am using MySQL as the DB.

I can query 1 table, all columns with the following code

```
 query = Q(term__contains=tt) | Q(portal__contains=tt) | ......so on
 data = ABC.objects.filter(query)
```

I tried to use the UNION, write a SQL like

```
select * from table A where col1 like %s OR col2 like %s .....
 UNION
 select * from table B where col1 like %s OR col2 like %s .....
```

When I tried to implement this like below, I got an **error "not enough arguments for format string"**

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("select * from table A where col1 like %s OR col2 like %s 
     UNION
     select * from table B where col1 like %s OR col2 like %s", tt)
```

So how do I pass the parameters for multiple variables(even though in this case they are the same)? I tried passing it multiple times too.

Thanks.

Comment: you may want to look at [django-watson](https://github.com/etianen/django-watson)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass a list of parameters.  Number of parameters should match the number of `%s` placeholders:

```
cursor.execute("select * from table A where col1 like %s OR col2 like %s 
                UNION
                select * from table B where col1 like %s OR col2 like %s",
                [tt] * 4) # four `%s`
```

As alternative you can try to use `numeric` [paramstyle](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#paramstyle) for the query.  In this case the list of a single parameter will be sufficient:

```
cursor.execute("select * from table A where col1 like :1 OR col2 like :1 
                UNION
                select * from table B where col1 like :1 OR col2 like :1",
                [tt])
```

**UPDATE**: Note that `tt` variable should contain `%` signs at start/end:

```
tt = u'%' + string_to_find + u'%'
```

**UPDATE 2**: `cursor.fetchall()` returns list of tuples (not dicts) so you should access this data by indexes:

```
{% for row in data %}
    <div>Col1: {{ row.0 }} - Col2: {{ row.1 }}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks. I have assigned the resultset data to the "data" object and assigning that to the context variable and trying to read it in the html. But I see empty rows. `data = cursor.fetchall()
for res in data:
    print(res)
context = {'data': data}` WHen I print, I see the records in the logs. Inhtml, I am reading the "data" object as data.field1, data.field2, assuming the field1 and field2 are the column names as specified in the model object for data. What am I missing here. Thanks again

Comment: Apologies if I am misunderstanding. My code looks like this now `tt = request.GET['q']
tt = u'%' + tt + u'%'
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT col1,col2 FROM TABLE_A WHERE col1 LIKE %s OR col2 LIKE %s UNION SELECT col1,col2 FROM TABLE_B WHERE col1 LIKE %s OR col2 LIKE %s  [tt]*4)
data_obj = cursor.fetchall()
context = {'data_obj': data_obj}`. I am still getting the same issue. Thanks again for your time and help.

Comment: Sorry, I inattentively read you first comment.  You should access columns by indexes.  See the second update to my answer.